# Buggy code completion in eclipse JavaScript Development Tools

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

I open a project with file => new => static web project. Name it MyProject and web content folder name is WebContent.

Right click the WebContent directory and add a js directory. Right click the js directory and choose new => other => JavaScript source file and call it DomStuff.js with the following content:

```
var MyApp={};
MyApp.DomStuff={};
MyApp.DomStuff.someFunction=function(){
  return true;
}
MyApp.do<== here it auto completes to DomStuff
```

Right click the js directory again and choose new => other => JavaScript source file and call it WorkFlow.js

When I type `MyApp.` then press control + space I get a box saying `No Default Proposals`. It's like auto complete only works when all the code is in one file.

Right click `JavaScript Resources` under the Source tab MyProject/WebContent is listed as included all and excluded none.

This is in Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 with   Eclipse Web Developer Tools    3.4.1 and     JavaScript Development Tools  1.4.1.

For as long as I remember I never got the auto complete to work on code outside the file I am currently working on. Is this normal or am I missing some setting here?

Comment: Have you tried Aptana?

Comment: @epascarello No, I have not tried it yet. I assumed that after so many years of developing JSDT it would work. I may be just a setting I'm missing somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[update]**
Basically Eclipse with JSDT can't do the job. Tried to define all my namespaces with constructor functions but it's all too much trouble.

Trying netbeans now and it'll assist most of the closure library and all of my code. Some things like goog.array won't complete because goog.array is never defined. When adding goog.array=new Object() to the array.js it'll complete goog.array and goog.array.ArrayLike. These modded js file go in your js/libs directory of your project.

If you want the troublesome way to get it to work in Eclipse then keep reading.

It seems that Eclipse has problems with objects declared as object literals. Declaring my complex types with a constructor function seems to do the trick. An instance of the root object has to be created on `Window` (capital W).

```
// this would be the way I would define
// a complex property that doesn't need
// more than one instance and is not complex
// enough to put in a separate file
myapp.workflow.objectLiteral={
  thisDoesNotCodeAssist:function(){},
  neitherDoesThis:22
};

/** if you define the complex property as
 *  a constructor it will auto complete
 *  in other files and closure compiler will 
 *  recognize it's type
 */
/** @constructor organizes flow 
 * used for Eclipse code assist */
var WorkFlow=function(){};
ProwpWithSubs=function(){};
PropWithSubs.prototype.subProp=22;
PropWithSubs.prototype.subFunction=function(){
  this.subsub=44;
};
WorkFlow.prototype.propwithsubs=new PropWithSubs();
if(ALLWAYSFALSE){
  /**needed for Eclipse code assist
   * @constructor
   */
  var MyApp=function(){};
  MyApp.prototype.workflow=new WorkFlow();
  MyApp.prototype.dom=new DOM();
  Window.prototype.myapp=new MyApp();
}else{
  myapp.workflow=new WorkFlow();
}
```

**[update]**

Here are 3 files I use to split up the definition and the implementation a little so it's easier with google closure.

Setting up the main types in types.js

```
// source: js/mmyapp/types.js
goog.provide("myapp.types");
/** @constructor */
var gooblediegoog=function(){};
/** @constructor */
gooblediegoog.prototype.WorkFlow=function(){};
/** @constructor */
gooblediegoog.prototype.Dom=function(){};
myapp.types=new gooblediegoog();
```

A file that isn't used at all in my code but tells Eclipse how to auto complete:

```
// source: js/myapp/forCodeAssist.js
/** @const {boolean} */
var ALLWAYSFALSE=false;

if(ALLWAYSFALSE){
    /**needed for Eclipse autocomplete
     * @constructor
     */
    var MyApp=function(){};
    MyApp.prototype.types=new gooblediegoog();
    Window.prototype.myapp=new MyApp();
    MyApp.prototype.workflow=new myapp.types.WorkFlow();
    MyApp.prototype.dom=new myapp.types.Dom();
}
```

An implementation of workflow:

```
// source: js/myapp/workflow.js
goog.provide("myapp.workflow");
goog.require("myapp.types");
goog.require("myapp.dom");

/** @returns number|undefined */
myapp.types.WorkFlow.prototype.createOrder=function(){
    return myapp.dom.getArticleAmout();
};
myapp.workflow=new myapp.types.WorkFlow();
window['console'].log(myapp.workflow.createOrder());
```

This can be converted to a `myapp.workflow.createOrder=...` syntax by replacing `myapp.types.WorkFlow.prototype` with `myapp.workflow`, removing `myapp.workflow=new myapp.types.WorkFlow()` and removing the `goog.require("myapp.types")`. Maybe this can be automated in the build/compile process if needed.

I am not sure if creating a single object with the help from a constructor function is much more expensive than just having `goog.require` create myapp.workflow and adding properties to it as I used to do (and as it's done in closure library).

Answer (score 0):

Standard JSDT can seem non deterministic when it come to completions across files. That is because even if the project is configured correctly then the most expensive type of it's source code analysis only occurs on files that are open. Do you get the same result if both files are open?

By the way, there is a fork of JSDT that is a candidate for merging to official JSDT called JSDT+NJSDoc that handles such cross file analysis extremely efficiently (and adds other features): https://bitbucket.org/nexj/webtools.jsdt.core

Comment: Thank you John, it seems JSDT has problems with object literals. If I declare my objects as (constructor) functions it works fine across files. When creating an object on `Window.prototype` (kapital W) it works and has code assist on every file just like `document.getEl...` will suggest in every file.

Comment: I have updated my question with the solution I am thinking about (not sure yet). I can close all files and have only one file open to have code assist on other files (even though they are closed). The syntax used in file that defines code assist for document in Eclipse looks a lot like the code in default externs used by the closure compiler. Every object is a function and every property is declared on the functions prototype.